# How to enable CORS on AZURE application gateway

Tags: .net-core, cors, signalr, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

how can I enable CORS on the Azure application gateway ? 
I have a signalhub running on 
Azure kubernetes service as a 
Dapr app.
The app has All .net cors policies setup correctly, issue seems to be from the JavaScript to the gateway.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Setting a rewrite rule on the application Gateway like below resolves the issue.

Answer (score 6):

You can enable **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** Responde Header in Rewrites, on your Application Gateway

[Enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin Responde Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7TWx.png)